# Pronunciation of [ 男爵 / だんしゃく ]

Tags: pronunciation

I was watching JoJo's Bizarre Adventure where Baron Zepelli introduces himself, and it sounds like he says ”私はZepelliだんしゃんだ”. Here's a link to the scene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWaAct40xZ0&t=1m1s. I looked up the word for baron and found 男爵 / だんしゃく. Am I hearing it wrong, or is the trailing くdropped? If it is dropped, then is it just some Japanese dialect or is there a rule for it?

Comment: Hmm, I hear the く pretty clearly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 声優{せいゆう}, voice actor pronounces 私はツェッペリ男爵{だんしゃく}だ as in the original scene. But he uses turn of the phrase from the noble. It might sound more different to your ear than as usual.

And the assertion「**だ**」sounds stronger than「**く**」to emphasize dignity and his upbringing.

It might confuse you.

The original scene from Jojo below actually put furigana-ruby for だんしゃく in 男爵.

**わたしは　ツェペリ男爵{だんしゃく}だ　勇気{ゆうき}だけでは「石仮面{いしかめん}」の力{ちから}には 勝{か}てんよォーーー**」

[image]

©荒木飛呂彦&LUCKY LAND COMMUNICATIONS/集英社

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm really bad at understanding spoken Japanese, and heard that kuda as nda, but after listening closer I can hear it now.

Comment: Where was the scene posted?

Comment: Search "ツェペリ男爵 ジョジョ" in Google images. You might need to switch the region from your region to Japan in 日本語, Japanese Language to search and know what originally it is as in the case like this.

Comment: @Matt Never mind. The pronunciation is peculiar to the character like this. It's  different than daily spoken Japanese.